# To work with two different drop downs which are dependent on each other

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

I have a scenario, which I am finding bit difficult to automate.

The test scenario is :

There are two drop down.

1. To select the state.
2. To select the respective cities.

So, I need to write a script to automate, where I need to select a state from State drop down and for that state I need to select all the cities one after the other. Once all the cities are selected for that respective state, I need to come out of that loop and select a different state and repeat this process.

This is the code which i have written.

```
    def test_state(self):
    element = self.getAllTheElements(self.Register_page_elements,'xpath', 'option')
    for link in element:
        if link.get_attribute('value'):
            link.click()
            print("test")
            time.sleep(4)
            element = self.getAllTheElements('autocomplete-city', 'id', 'option')
            for link2 in element:
                if link2.get_attribute("value"):
                    link2.click()
                    print("state")
                    time.sleep(2)
```

Since I have not given break statement, it will throw an error after completing entire iteration.

But, if I give a break it wont work the way I want.

This is the HTML code of the drop down.

For state.

```
<div class="under-line">
                        <select type="text" class="enque-content" autocomplete="off" required="required" id="autocomplete-state" name="state" onchange="getCities(this)">
                            <option selected="" disabled="disabled" value="">Please select your state*</option>
                        <option value="1">Andaman and Nicobar Island</option><option value="2">Andhra Pradesh</option><label alt="First Name*" class="enque-placeholder-label" placeholder="First Name*"> </label><option value="3">Arunachal Pradesh</option><option value="4">Assam</option><option value="5">Bihar</option><option value="6">Chandigarh</option><option value="8">Dadra and Nagar Haveli</option><option value="7">Chhattisgarh</option><option value="9">Daman and Diu</option><option value="10">Delhi</option><option value="37">Goa</option><option value="12">Gujarat</option><option value="13">Haryana</option><option value="14">Himachal Pradesh</option><option value="15">Jammu and Kashmir</option><option value="16">Jharkhand</option><option value="17">Karnataka</option><option value="18">Kerala</option><option value="19">Lakshadweep</option><option value="20">Madhya Pradesh</option><option value="21">Maharashtra</option><option value="22">Manipur</option><option value="23">Meghalaya</option><option value="24">Mizoram</option><option value="25">Nagaland</option><option value="26">Odisha</option><option value="27">Puducherry</option><option value="28">Punjab</option><option value="29">Rajasthan</option><option value="30">Sikkim</option><option value="31">Tamil Nadu</option><option value="32">Telangana</option><option value="33">Tripura</option><option value="34">Uttar Pradesh</option><option value="35">Uttarakhand</option><option value="36">West Bengal</option></select>
                    </div>
```

Once I select the state then the city drop down will appear.

Comment: Can you share the code of dropdown?

Comment: Why do you need to select all cities for each state in turn? If your goal is to verify that the correct cities for each state are loaded it's possible there is a different method depending on how the web page is coded. Without knowing the reason you need the test and the web page code, it's not possible to give you a good answer

Comment: Its a registration page , so i need to write a code where a user will be registered to each city @KatePaulk

Comment: @AlexeyR. this is the code for state drop down

Comment: i got the solution for my question thank you for all the help

Comment: The best pattern to do this is the PageObject pattern, remember that a PageObject can be a page fragment (it should be called the PagePartObject).   I'd suggest wrapping each drop down into 'visual control' classes and contain those in a controls group class that is a PageObject.  Then follow the tell don't ask idiom in the group class.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code...
To select the state,

```
WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.Id("your locator value"));
Select stateoption = new Select(elem);
stateoption.SelectByVisibleText("");
```

Above code selects a specified "state" form the dropdown.Once the "state" is selected,the cities will be listed out .So for selecting the cities try the code,

```
List<WebElement> ele = driver.findElements(By.Xpath(""));
for(WebElement cities:elem) {
   if(!cities.isSelected()) cities.click();
}
```

Please comment out if you find any issues.

Comment: i require python code @shanila ,but still thank your for your answer

Answer (score 0):

I got answer to my question.

By using two **for** loops for both, state and city drop down I was able get the desired result.

```
   def test_state(self):                                                                                        
    element = self.get_element('autocomplete-state', 'id')                                                             
    for state in element.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):                            
        state.click()                                                                                                               
        element = self.get_element('autocomplete-city', 'id')                                                                                       
        for city in element.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):                                                                          
            city.click()
```